# Find the missing angle in the triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Given the following triangle $ABC$, find the angle of $ACD$.

[image]

Notice that $AC = BC$, I can find the orthocenter of $ABC$. However, I am stucked and do not know what is the next step. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the orthocenter you found?

Comment: Just draw three heights in the traingle

Comment: (almost) identical to http://www.gogeometry.com/school-college/p992-triangle-interior-point-20-30-40-50-degree-angle.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the trigonometric form of the [Ceva's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml) we obtain:

$$\frac{\sin\angle ACD}{\sin\angle BCD}=\frac{\sin40^\circ\sin50^\circ}{\sin30^\circ\sin20^\circ}=\frac{2\sin40^\circ\cos40^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}
=\frac{\sin80^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}=\frac{\cos10^\circ}{2\sin10^\circ\cos10^\circ}=\frac{\sin30^\circ}{\sin10^\circ}.$$

From this and $$\angle ACD+\angle BCD=40^\circ$$ one concludes:
$$
\angle ACD=30^\circ,\quad \angle BCD=10^\circ.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution! However, I am still looking for solving this problem with only elementary geometry techniques. Is it possible to show that this problem is not solvable without trigonometry?

Comment: Considering the simplicity of the answer I cannot exclude that there is a "pure" geometric solution for these specific angles. However it will be not so general as mine.